# How to share resource ids between client and server in Android?

Tags: android, localization, client-server

I am writing a client (android) /server (java) application. Server returns true or "false and error code" for every request made by client. I added every error message (string) to strings.xml in client side.

This is how i keep error codes;

```
public class ErrorCodes {
    public static final int WRONG_USERNAME = 1;
    public static final int WRONG_PASSWORD = 2;
    public static final int WRONG_EMAIL= 3;
    ...
}
```

The problem is, everytime server sends an error code, i have to handle it like that (roughly);

```
int code = conn.receive();
if(code == ErrorCodes.WRONG_USERNAME)
    print(getResources().getString(R.string.WRONG_USERNAME_ERROR));
else if(code == ErrorCodes.WRONG_PASSWORD)
    print(getResources().getString(R.string.WRONG_PASSWORD_ERROR));
...
```

There are two approaches in my mind to ease this process but both not elegant.

*Approach 1:* Making ErrorCodes values equal to R.string values manually. Also with this approach i don't need to keep ErrorCodes class in client side too.

*Problem:* I have to update both ErrorCodes and strings.xml everytime i add a new error message.

*Approach 2:* Use generated R.java file in server, no need to update anything. This is the best i can think of.

*Problem(s):* There will be a lot of unnecessary stuff comes with R.java. I have to use it like that in server side: `R.string.xyz`. And if server is not coded with java, whole approach is useless.

If i use one of these, i can do this in client side;

```
int code = conn.receive();
print(getResources().getString(code));
```

I think there is a better way i can not think of. Because both way sounds painfully. How to handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to keep your approach.
It will leads you to write some code for handling all the cases but at the end, for me, is the most robust solution because:

1. Your server won't be Android dependent. The logic behing your server will be valid for Android only. In case tomorrow you will develop one client for another platform it would be much better to have a platform-indipendent protocol.
2. Every time your edit your app, adding new resources and so on, your R file is generated again and `R.string.something` could have a different value than the previous build. So, in the situation you are rolling out an app update your users could experience strange errors because in the versione 1 of your app the resource 12345 could point to `R.string.something` and in the version 2 could point to `R.string.something_else`. But maybe for this point there is a method for keep a static `R.string` value.

The following solution seems acceptable to me:

Your server returns some code for your errors, for example:

```
1 for WRONG_USERNAME
2 for WRONG_PASSWORD
3 for WRONG_EMAIL
```

you could declare the string is this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="error_1">Wrong username!</string>
    <string name="error_2">Wrong password!</string>
    <string name="error_3">Wrong email!</string>
</resources>
```

And then you load the string resource by name:

```
int stringId = getResources().getIdentifier("error_"+errorCode,"string",getPackageName());
```

Comment: You are right about server dependency, it was my mistake to even think about that. I decided to use a similar method to what you suggested. I used a Hashtable object; `errors.put(ErrorCode, R.string.ERROR_WRONG_USERNAME)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same method you described in approach 1

If you  only want to print errors, think about using json to send data from serwer, e.g.:

```
if(logged_on == true){
    server.send("{\"status\":0}");
}else{
    server.send("{\"status\":1,\"error\":"+ErrorString);
}
```

Then on the client side check the status field, and if equals 1 print string from the error field.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is obviously to keep error description strings on server, but that could introduce additional complexity for localization. You would need to send device's current interface language to the server to get correct error description
Otherwise I would use a short textual error identifiers on server side (e.g. "no_data_found", "db_timeout", etc) - something which makes sense and makes it easier to debug and modify string table for the android app.
On the client side, I would add corresponding error description strings, with identifiers following some standard scheme. For example: "error_no_data_found", "error_db_timeout".
Then, to retrieve error description string, you could use a reflection:

```
String getErrorString(String stringName)
{
    try
    {
        Field f_a =R.string.class.getDeclaredField(stringName);
        int a = f_a.getInt(null);
        return getString(a);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException x)
    {
        return "No error description for "+stringName;
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException x)
    {
        return "";
    }       
}

...
String errorDescription = getErrorString("error_"+errorCodeReceivedFromServer);
```

Also, you can write a script to check if all of the server error identifiers have corresponding entries in strings.xml file.